# how to make a php function loop every 5 seconds

Tags: php

I am tyring to make a php function that updates every second using php itself no other languages, just pure PHP codes.

```
function exp(){
//do something
}
```

I want it to return a value each second. Like update every second.

Comment: Looks like you don't understand how php works. What's the target of updating every second?

Comment: Its actually updating the time. Its actually a PHP function.

Comment: Updating time where? In client browser?

Comment: In the comment, like 1 second ago, 5 seconds ago. I want it to keep updating.

Comment: Please read how web works. And for your task use javascript.

Comment: Just another [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score -7, accepted):

It's not preferable to make this in PHP, try to make on client side by calculating difference between time you got from database and current time.
you can make this in JS like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
      // method to be executed;
    },5000);  // run every 5 seconds
```

Comment: The question is how to get the value from database while im using jquery?

Comment: Use ajax.. look at this example:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax

Comment: for example there is php function in same page, how to call it

Comment: is this actually an answer ?

Comment: Yes, only in client side.

Answer (score 10):

For an application server (not a web server), best practice is to use an event loop pattern instead of sleep. This gives you the ability to run multiple timers should the need arise (sleep is blocking so nothing else can run in the mean time). Web servers on the other hand should not really be executing any long-running scripts.

Whilst other languages give you event loops out of the box (node / js for example, with setInterval), PHP does not, so you have to either use a well known library or make your own). React PHP is a widely used event loop for PHP.

Here is a quick-and-dirty "hello world" implementation of an event loop

```php
define("INTERVAL", 5 ); // 5 seconds

function runIt() { // Your function to run every 5 seconds
    echo "something\n";
}

function checkForStopFlag() { // completely optional
    // Logic to check for a program-exit flag
    // Could be via socket or file etc.
    // Return TRUE to stop.
    return false;
}

function start() {
    $active = true;
    $nextTime   = microtime(true) + INTERVAL; // Set initial delay

    while($active) {
        usleep(1000); // optional, if you want to be considerate

        if (microtime(true) >= $nextTime) {
            runIt();
            $nextTime = microtime(true) + INTERVAL;
        }

        // Do other stuff (you can have as many other timers as you want)           

        $active = !checkForStopFlag();
    }
}

start();
```

In the real world you would encapsulate this nicely in class with all the whistles and bells.

Word about threading:

PHP is single threaded under the hood (any OS threading must be manually managed by the programmer which comes with a significant learning curve). So every task in your event loop will hold up the tasks that follow. Node on the other hand, for example manages OS threads under the hood, taking that "worry" away from the programmer (which is a topic of much debate). So when you call setInterval(), the engine will work its magic so that the rest of your javascript will run concurrently.

Quick final note:
It could be argued that this pattern is overkill if all you want to do is have a single function do something every 5 seconds. But in the case where you start needing concurrent timers, sleep() will not be the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 5):

`sleep()` function is the function that you are looking for:

```
while (true) {
    my_function(); // Call your function
    sleep(5);
}
```

1. While loop with always true
2. Call your function inside while loop
3. Wait for 5 seconds(sleep)
4. Return the beginning of the loop

By the way it's not a logical use case of endless loops in PHP if you are executing the script through a web protocol(HTTP, HTTPS, etc.) because you will get a [timeout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeout_(computing)). A rational use case could be a periodic database updater or a web crawler.

Such scripts can be executed through command line using `php myscript.php` or an alternative (but not recommended) way is using [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to extend the limit if you insist on using a web protocol to execute the script.

Comment: What does it do? Can u explain in depth so that i can understand

Comment: @Bido262 More explanation added to answer.

Comment: I hope this will work, actually inside the while loop should i put something like fetch_assoc or array, or ill only put true?
Does it update asynchronously without  refreshing the page?

Comment: Though this function does what you wrote in a title of your question, this is **not** what you're looking for.

Comment: I came up here as I am about to find an answer. I tried yours but it just loads for no more or less than 30 seconds for its the default maxtimelimit. Not to be best used before all the codes in your page

Comment: @JimwelAnobong of course you will get timeout if you request the execution through a web protocol. It's also illogical to call an endless loop through HTTP/HTTPS. Execute the script through command line using `php myscript.php` or use [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to extend the limit.

Answer (score 2):

```
function exp(){
//do something
}
while(true){
exp();
sleep(5);
}
```

Use sleep function to make execution sleep for 5 seconds

it will be better if you use setInterval and use ajax to perform your action

Comment: this only delays the execution of a php function?

Comment: Not what im looking for sorry.

Comment: I know that's why you must use javascript to perform this task

Answer (score 2):

Suppose exp() is your function

```
function exp(){
 //do something
}
```

Now we are starting a do-while loop

```
$status=TRUE;

do { 

   exp(); // Call your function
   sleep(5);   //wait for 5 sec for next function call

   //you can set $status as FALSE if you want get out of this loop.

   //if(somecondition){
   //    $status=FALSE:
   //}

} while($status==TRUE); //loop will run infinite
```

I hope this one helps :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$t0  = microtime(true);
$i   = 0;
do{     
    $dt = round(microtime(true)-$t0);
    if($dt!= $i){
        $i = $dt;
        if(($i % 5) == 0) //every 5 seconds
            echo $i.PHP_EOL;
    }   
}while($dt<10); //max execution time
```