# substr my string in a while(true) every secounds

Tags: php

I wanna substr() my string every secounds in php..
The problem is it substr only 1 string and stop..
Code:

```
$string = "This is a test";
While(true) {
  substr($string,0,-1);
  if ($string = "") {
  $string = "This is a test"; 
  sleep(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: `substr()` doesn't change your string, it returns the new value. So you have to `$string = substr($string, 0, -1);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185302/how-to-make-a-php-function-loop-every-5-seconds

refer this may be helping!

Comment: `if ($string = "") {` is not a comparison.. also where is the `sleep(1)` (secounds)?, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This dont works @Holger, It gives me the same: `This is a tes`

Comment: I want that this remove every secound 1 string and then if the string is empty give full string back

Comment: You might as well do, `$str = 'This is a test'; sleep(strlen($str)); echo $str;` It will work the same ;p

Comment: It give me nothing out here is an small example with the String "test"  `test -> tes -> te -> t -> blank <- if its blank then the word will be back to "test"

Comment: It can't stop `while(true)`... Because $string gets never changed, your program runs in a loop, cuts the last character from $string (which is "This is a test" in every loop)  and throws the result away. This runs with max. speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = "This is a test";
while(true) 
{
  $string = substr($string,0,-1);
  if ($string == "") 
  {
      $string = "This is a test";
  }
  echo $string;
  sleep(1);
}
```